# PHP shuffle like mysql order by rand(seed)

Tags: php, mysql, random, shuffle

How do you shuffle an array in PHP but preserve the order of the shuffle when an element is inserted or deleted like mysql order by rand(seed) does?
A kind of Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm that ignores the length of the array.

Lets assume you have an array with A,B,C and you run this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT 'A' AS value 
  UNION 
  SELECT 'B' AS value 
  UNION 
  SELECT 'C' AS value) AS T order by rand(123)
```

The result will be B,C,A.

Now if you add D to the list of elements:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT 'A' AS value 
  UNION 
  SELECT 'B' AS value 
  UNION 
  SELECT 'C' AS value 
  UNION 
  SELECT 'D' AS value) AS T order by rand(123)
```

The result will be D,B,C,A.

Adding element E to the list:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT 'A' AS value 
  UNION 
  SELECT 'B' AS value 
  UNION 
  SELECT 'C' AS value 
  UNION 
  SELECT 'D' AS value 
  UNION 
  SELECT 'E' AS value) AS T order by rand(123)
```

The result will be D,B,C,E,A.

Fisher-Yates will provide a totally different order when you add the element "D" to the array, while mysql order by rand(seed) will insert element "D" somewhere in the already random sorted list.

Comment: Do you mean: You take an initial list and 'shuffle it'. Then, as separate steps, you insert or delete items in 'random positions' but never shuffle the list again?

Comment: Can you share what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Lets say I have 80 premium car sale listings, and i display 10 per page. I need them to be random throughout the day(seed=current day), but when clients add new listings, i want to keep the same random order and insert the new listings among the others without giving the new elements more weight, otherwise all clients would delete/insert their listings to get to the top.

Answer (score 3):

You can mimic sort-by-rand behavior in a way similar to this:

```
function sort_by_rand($ary, $seed) {
    srand($seed);
    $tmp = array_map(function($x) { return [rand(), $x]; }, $ary);
    sort($tmp);
    return array_map(function($x) { return $x[1]; }, $tmp);
}
```

Results:

```
$ary = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
print_r(sort_by_rand($ary, 100)); // CBA

$ary = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
print_r(sort_by_rand($ary, 100)); // CBAD

$ary = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
print_r(sort_by_rand($ary, 100)); // CBAED
```